# UV Texture from Photoshop won't show

Tags: texturing, uv

So I am making my first UV-mapping and have been following a video on Youtube. 
I have UV-mapped my model, baked it and colored it in photoshop.

I have also saved it as a PSD file and opened it in the UV-window in Blender, but the model is blank. My viewport is in texture, but the model appears to be the same as when I baked it. In the video, the texture just appeared automatically.
Am I missing something here?

( I have Blender 2.74 + Photoshop CS5. I have tried opening it as a PSD file and a JPG, and I have tried changing cameras and changing to Edit mode)

Thanks for reading

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you turned on `GLSL` Shading? (`Properties` panel -> Shading > dropdown menu). After that the texture should be shown when in `Texture` mode.

Comment: Hello again. I found the GLSL option (see new image) and turned everything on. Yet no result :( Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Have you created and applied the materials and textures to the model? You didn't mention that in the answer. It doesn't matter that the model has been UV unvrapped, there will be no images seen in `Texture` mode if textures hasn't been created (so and materials) and images you need haven't been opened in `Image or Movie` scroll.

Comment: Thank you Zak, that solved it. In the Youtube-video he just opened the new UV image and the texture came on. But I created a new material with Image Texture and used the UV-file. Thank you so much!